# Mysql result set for last 2 hours

Tags: mysql, date, select, between

Look at this query:

```
SELECT attempt_time, u.username
  FROM login_attempts l 
  JOIN user u ON u.user_id = l.user_id AND  u.username = 'jhone' 

+---------------------+---------------+
| attempt_time        | username      |
+---------------------+---------------+
| 2021-07-27 16:06:48 | jhone         |
| 2021-07-27 16:34:33 | jhone         |
| 2021-07-27 16:34:46 | jhone         |
| 2021-07-27 16:39:53 | jhone         |
| 2021-07-27 18:33:30 | jhone         |
| 2021-07-27 18:34:13 | jhone         |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

Just I need to get `attempt_time` for last 2 hours:

This is How I tried, But it always giving empty set as result.

```
SELECT attempt_time, u.username
  FROM login_attempts l 
    JOIN user u ON u.user_id = l.user_id AND  u.username = 'jhone' 
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN l.attempt_time AND NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

Can anyone tell why my query doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last 2 hours means:

```
WHERE l.attempt_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND NOW();
```

Or maybe:

```
WHERE l.attempt_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

if there are no rows after `NOW()`.

Comment: Does the same result set come from both these conditions?

Comment: @user3733831 if there are no rows in the table with attempt_time later than NOW() then they return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic in the `WHERE` clause is off.  Try this version:

```sql
SELECT attempt_time, u.username
FROM login_attempts l 
INNER JOIN user u ON u.user_id = l.user_id
WHERE u.username = 'jhone'  AND
      l.attempt_time BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

Note that if there is no data in the futute, the `WHERE` clause can be simplified to:

```sql
WHERE u.username = 'jhone'  AND l.attempt_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

Comment: Before ask this question, I tried like this, but it also gives empty set.

Comment: Maybe then you don't have any matching data.  You may be after a calendar table approach here, but without seeing data I can't be certain.

Comment: Your second conditon `l.attempt_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` is worked for me